# Error de compilación en c++ haciendo listas polimorficas: 'lista': no se permiten las listas de parámetros de plantilla múltiple

Tags: c++, lista, template, polimorfismo

Estoy tratando de crear una lista en c++ usando visual studio enterprise 2015. El problema que tengo es que me apareció un error, mientras definía los métodos de la clase lista, que busque cómo solucionarlo y no encontré nada. El error es el siguiente: 'lista': no se permiten las listas de parámetros de plantilla múltiple.
El código es el siguiente:

```
        #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class nodo {
    friend class lista<T>;
public:
    nodo(const T&);
    T getDatoNodo() const;
    ~nodo();
private:
    T dato;
    nodo <T> *sig;
};

template <class T>
nodo<T>::nodo(const T &D) {
    dato = D;
    sig = 0;
}

template <class T>
nodo<T>::~nodo() {}

template <class T>
T nodo<T>::getDatoNodo() const
{
    return dato;
}
/////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////

template <class T>
class lista {
public:
    lista();
    ~lista();
    void altaPrincipio(const T&);
    void altaFinal(const T&);
    void bajaPrincipio();
    void bajaFinal();
    void imprimirDato() const;
    bool vacia() const;
    bool presente(const T&) const;
    int cuentaNodos() const;
private:
    nodo <T> *p;
};

template <class T>
lista<T>::lista() { p = NULL; }


template <class T>
lista<T>::~lista() {
    while (!vacia())
        bajaPrincipio();
    delete p;
}

template <class T>
void lista<T>::altaPrincipio(const T &D) {
    nodo <T> *aux;
    aux = new nodo <T>;//Creo un dato aux de tipo T (el que venga)
    aux->dato = D;//-> es el operador para asimilar a objetos de una clase que son punteros
    aux->sig = p;
    p = aux;
}

template <class T>
void lista<T>::altaFinal(const T &D) {
    nodo <T> *aux, *sec;
    aux = new nodo <T>;
    aux->dato = D;
    if (vacia()) p = aux;
    else
    {
        while (sec->sig)//el siguiente de sec sea distinto de 0, o sea que hay algo....
            sec = sec->sig;
    }
}

template <class T>
void lista<T>::bajaPrincipio() {
    nodo <T> *aux=p;
    if (!vacia())
    {
        p = p->sig;
        delete aux;
    }
}

template <class T>
void lista<T>::bajaFinal() {
    nodo <T> *aux, *sec;
    if (!vacia()) {
        aux = p;
        if (aux->sig == NULL) {
            p = NULL;
            delete aux;
        }
        else {
            while (aux->sig->sig != NULL)
                aux = aux->sig;
            sec = aux->sig;
            aux->sig = NULL;
            delete sec;
        }
    }
}

template <class T>
int lista<T>::cuentaNodos() const{
    if (vacia()) return 0;
    else {
        nodo <T> *aux = p;
        int cuenta = 0;
        while (aux) {
            cuenta++;
            aux = aux->sig;
        }
        return cuenta;
    }
}

template <class T>
bool lista<T>::vacia() const{
    return (p == 0);//Retorno el valor binario de la operacion ==
}

template <class T>
void lista<T>::imprimirDato() const{
    if (!vacia()) {
        nodo <T> *aux = p;
        while (aux) {
            cout << aux->dato << endl;
            aux = aux->sig;
        }
    }
}

template <class T>
bool lista<T>::presente(const T &valor) const {
    if (vacia()) return false;
    else {
        nodo<T> *aux = p;
        while (aux && (aux->dato) != valor)
            aux = aux->sig;
        if (!aux) return false;
        else return true;
    }
}
```

[introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnpHn.png)
Todavia no está hecho el destructor pero se puede observar que los errores se acumulan, por lo que el problema proviene de antes, y por lo que se ve, el problema está en el template. Si me lo pueden solucionar me harían un gran favor, gracias!!!

Comment: Aparte del error `error: 'dato' does not name a type`, que no tiene nada que ver con el que comentas, tu código no es completo (faltan, por ejemplo, el destructor de `lista`). Por favor, edita la pregunta para que sea completa y corrije los errores de compilación (son 2 idénticos)

Comment: También sería intereasante que comentases en qué línea te está dando el error

Comment: Me falta escribir lo otro, pero más tarde lo puedo hacer...pasa que yo venía escribiendo lo que hicimos en la universidad. Terminé de hacer los nodos y hasta ahí todo bien... pero después cuando empecé con la lista surgió un problema (con los templates seguramente) y después todas las demás líneas también tenían errores que se ve que se debían a eso. Le saqué un screenshot, cuando pueda edito la publicación

Comment: El problema es que el error que comentas no es reproducible y, en cambio, el código tiene otros errores que no has comentado y que para corregirlos basta con leer el mensaje de error

Comment: Aún me falta terminar el destructor que más tarde lo hago, pero por ahora ahí están todos los errores que se me acumularon...el tema es que esos dos errores de compilación que dices no sé cómo solucionarlos... yo leo esto y para mí está bien

Comment: Es que lo que yo busco es que sea polimorfica la lista y por lo que busqué en internet la forma de hacerlo es esta....de última elimino la publicación y más tarde reformulo la pregunta

Comment: Son errores tontos porque estás confundiendo `dato` con `nodo`. `dato` no existe. no es una clase ni una estructura ni tipo definido... en cambio `nodo` sí lo es. De hecho en la declaración de la variable demuestras que sí que sabes que vas a trabajar con punteros de tipo `nodo`: `nodo <T> *aux, *sec; aux = new dato<T>;`

Comment: Otra cosa es que tengas un tipo `dato` en tu código y no lo haas puesto aquí

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66138/discussion-between-eferion-and-f-riggio).

Comment: Como que no existe? Si está declarado en la clase nodo....pero como lo solucionarias??

Comment: Ah, en un momento lo había hecho por otro error para solucionarlo y olvide cambiarlo...tienes razón. Cuando pueda lo hago y te aviso

Answer (score 0):

Al final había que escribir antes de declarar al nodo `template <class T> class lista;`. Lo que ocurre es que al leer de arriba para abajo el compilador, y llegar al friend, no sabía quién era lista. Entonces para avisarle de antemano quien era, al llegar a esa línea, había que escribir eso

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es la necesidad de usar `friend` en este código. Basta un `get` para obtener el puntero al siguiente nodo para acabar con esa relacion de dependencia. No conviene abusar de esa palabra...